# how to parse array and create new array with parsed values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
var data = new Array("1111_3", "1231_54", "1143_76", "1758_12");
```

now I want to parse data[0] to get 1111.

```
var ids = new Array();
// example: ids = Array("1111", "1231", "1143", "1758");
```

and copy all ids from data to ids Array.

is it possible to do it like in php or do i need to use loops?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elegance:

```
data.map(function(x){
    return x.split('_')[0];
})
```

This IS part of the ECMA-262 standard.

But, if you care about supporting old outdated sub-par browsers, use jQuery (or whatever other framework you are using; almost all of them define a custom `map` function):

```
$.map(data, function(x){
    return x.split('_')[0];
})
```

Comment: @Jacob: "to do this one thing would be quite dumb". Well I am glad you think I am dumb. I have minor other reasons to include it, but if you prefer to type cross-platform compatible `for(var i=0;i<foo.length;i++){...}` constantly (try writing a nested for loop in this style: you can't), to each his own.

Comment: I don't think you're dumb. I'm just saying that to include `jQuery` for this one reason would not be worth it IMO. If you wrote your own imp of `map`, that's another thing.

Comment: @Jacob apologies, yes I agree that if bloat is an issue (e.g. mobile app), and ignoring CDNs and caching, then a custom `map` implementation (which is not added to Array.prototype) is probably preferable

Comment: Thank you, I am using Jquery and this is faster then loop

Comment: @Vural I would be suspicious that it is faster than the loop, especially if you have a small loop. You may be seeing another effect. $.map is nothing but syntactic sugar for `function (a,c,d){var f,g,h=[],i=0,j=a.length,k=a instanceof e||j!==b&&typeof j=="number"&&(j>0&&a[0]&&a[j-1]||j===0||e.isArray(a));if(k)for(;i<j;i++)f=c(a[i],i,d),f!=null&&(h[h.length]=f);else for(g in a)f=c(a[g],g,d),f!=null&&(h[h.length]=f);return h.concat.apply([],h)}` If you care about efficiency, you actually may want a pure for loop. Note that `[1,2,3].map` CAN however be optimized by the interpreter differently.

Answer (score 3):

Really simple:

```
var ids = [];
for(var i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; ++i) {
   var idString = data[i];
   ids.push(idString.substring(0, idString.indexOf('_')));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jacob, but this slows down the page.

Comment: @Vural I cannot imagine any reason this standard construct would slow down the page; you may be seeing some other effect, such as a background process, or a hickup in the browser.

Comment: +1 for a nice simple solution that doesn't suggest libraries or functions that older browsers might not support. Another option rather than `split` is `parseInt()`, given that it ignores everything in the string from the first non-numeric character. There's no way this is going to slow down the page (at least not compared with other possible solutions).

Comment: It's interesting to note that you introduce a j in the loop as a premature optimization where as in reality setting ids.length correctly in the beginning and  instead of split that will create two strings one of which would be discarded , using something like str.substr( 0 , str.indexof('_') ) might be actually more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called a 'map.'
Some browsers support them, but if you want to be safe you can use underscore.js (http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)

You'd end up with either:

```
_(data).map(function(x){
    return x.split('_')[0];
});
```

or

```
_.map(data, function(x){
    return x.split('_')[0];
});
```

Comment: I would not so much call them 'maps', but rather 'to map' or 'mapping' is a functional language paradigm which just means to return the result of applying a function to every element.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **really** big array it may be faster to join it to a string and split the string, rather than using any of the iterative methods to form it one by one.

```
var data = ["1111_3", "1231_54", "1143_76", "1758_12"];

var ids= data.join(' ').replace(/_\d+/g,'').split(' ');

alert(ids)

/*  returned value: (Array)
1111,1231,1143,1758
*/
```